# Playing a transparent video on screen

Tags: c#, video, sharpdx

I have tried to look around internet if there is a way to play a video transparent and without a window on screen (Like some kind of overlay, hud [Can't name it] or those legit Softonic 'animated christmas tree for desktop')

I first tried Windows Forms with Windows Media Player, but that did not work.

Now I'm taking a look into SharpDX, to see if that could work. I downloaded MediaPlayer sample from [GitHub link](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/MediaFoundation/MediaEngineAppVideo/Program.cs), it works and plays my selected video, but I have no idea how to get it transparent.

The video I am trying to play is 30 second loop and it has audio. I used a video editor to key all the background I did not want to be there.

Edit:

Now I know what to describe the effect, BonziBuddy (Don't grab the nukes yet, this is just an example of the effect I want). Here's also quick paint draw [Pasteboard link](http://pasteboard.co/2kgUOxVdh.jpg).